# Export current iframe content as HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, export, innerhtml

Here is the thing - I'm trying to create kind of email signature generator. Most of the index file, is a pure HTML code + tiny javascript. Inside index file I'm embeding email signature template as an iframe/email_signature.html file. So it looks as follows:

```
<iframe src="email_signature.html" width="100%" height="350" frameborder="0" id="testing" name="emailSignature"></iframe>
```

Then I'm trying to download current content of this iframe by executing this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        const innerFrame = document.getElementById('testing').contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
    $("#cmd").click(function(){
        exportFile('new-file.html', $innerFrame.innerHTML);
    }); 
});
```

but it doesn't work. Here is the example fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/py1tojmc/

What I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see in the dev console opening your jsfiddle, i don't see any "event" attached to your download button.
[image]

I can't tell you why this is happening (I'm not that expert), but maybe the call to `.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;` is somehow changing the DOM context to the iframe (just a guess), and it seems you cannot access the button id `#cmd` anymore.

Try changing your code like this ans see if it works:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#cmd").click(function(){
        const innerFrame = document.getElementById('testing').contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
        exportFile('new-file.html', $innerFrame.innerHTML);
    }); 
});
```

Comment: it does not generate expected results. Take a look on the final page: https://colorfill.pl/qubicgames/ - clicking the button erease everything what was generated in the iframe

Comment: When you click the button, I see an error in the console saying that `exportFile is not defined`. Where are you defining it?

Comment: well it was probably my fault.. i was thinking that exportFile is a jquery command. So jsut to understand the code better, exportFile is a function which I need to define, right?

Comment: Well, googling exportFile jQuery I could not find any reference to such a function, so I guess yeah you should probably define it yourself or find something else ready-to-use (don't know what to suggest though).

Answer (score 0):

Yeah looks like the button event won't fire. But could be cross origin security:

`SecurityError: Permission denied to access property "document" on cross-origin object`

But that could just be the jsfiddle, can you put an `alert('cmd button works');` just to make sure your button fires?

Comment: alert works perfectly, when I've reupload the script to my server, clicking on the button simply refresh the iframe content. take a look: https://colorfill.pl/qubicgames/